# Is there any chance to turn the quotient set by conjugation into a group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $\sim_{conj}$ the equivalence relation on $G$ by conjugation, and $cl(a)$ the conjugacy class of $a\in G$. If $\forall a,b\in G$:
$$a'\in cl(a)\wedge b'\in cl(b)\Longrightarrow a'b'\in cl(ab) \tag 1$$
then the operation in $G/\sim_{conj}$:
$$cl(a)\star cl(b):=cl(ab)$$
would be well-defined and fulfilling all the axioms to turn $G/\sim_{conj}$ into a (quotient) group. Are there $G$'s fulfilling the condition $(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the abelian groups (for which (1) is trivial). In fact, assume that $G/\sim_{conj}$ is a quotient group, and consider the projection map $\pi\colon G \to G/\sim_{conj}$. We have that $\ker \pi=cl(e)=\{e\}$ is trivial, and so $\pi$ is injective. It follows that $\pi$ is an isomorphism, and so $cl(a)=\{a\}$ for all $a \in G$. Therefore, for every $a, b \in G$ we have that $bab^{-1}=a$, i.e. $ba=ab$, and so $G$ is abelian.